# How to get element from multiple URLs appending each one?

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

I have a website that has a main URL containing several links. I want to get the first `<p>` element from each link on that main page.

I have the following code that works fine to get the desired links from main page and stores them in `urls` array. But my issue is 
that I don't know how to make a loop to load each url from `urls` array and print each `first <p>` in each iteration or append them 
in a variable and print all at the end.

How can I do this? thanks

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var main_url = 'http://www.someurl.com';

request(main_url, function(err, resp, body){
$ = cheerio.load(body);
links = $('a'); //get all hyperlinks from main URL
var urls = [];

//With this part I get the links (URLs) that I want to scrape.
$(links).each(function(i, link){
    lnk = 'http://www.someurl.com/files/' + $(link).attr('href');
    urls.push(lnk);
});

//In this part I don't know how to make a loop to load each url within urls array and get first <p>
    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) { 

        var p = $("p:first") //first <p> element
        console.log(p.html());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can successfully get the URLs from the first `<p>`, you already know everything to do that so I suppose you have issues with the way `request` is working and in particular with the callback based workflow.

My suggestion is to drop `request` since it's deprecated. You can use something like [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) which is Promise based so you can use the newer `async`/`await` features coming with it (which usually means easier workflow) (Though, you need to use at least nodejs 8 then!).

Your loop would look like this:

```js
for (const i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  const source = await got(urls[i]);
  // Do your cheerio determination
  console.log(new_p.html());
}
```

Mind you, that your function signature needs to be adjusted. In your case you didn't specify a function at all so the module's function signature is used which means you can't use `await`. So write a function for that:

```js
async function pullAllUrls() {
  const mainSource = await got(main_url);
  ...
}
```

If you don't want to use `async`/`await` you could work with some promise reductions but that's rather cumbersome in my opinion. Then rather go back to promises and use a workflow library like [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) to help you manage the URL fetching.

**A real example with async/await:**

In a real life example, I'd create a function to fetch the source of the page I'd like to fetch, like so (don't forget to add got to your script/package.json):

```js
async function getSourceFromUrl(thatUrl) {
  const response = await got(thatUrl);
  return response.body;
}
```

Then you have a workflow logic to get all those links in the other page. I implemented it like this:

```js
async function grabLinksFromUrl(thatUrl) {
  const mainSource = await getSourceFromUrl(thatUrl);
  const $ = cheerio.load(mainSource);
  const hrefs = [];

  $('ul.menu__main-list').each((i, content) => {
    $('li a', content).each((idx, inner) => {
      const wantedUrl = $(inner).attr('href');
      hrefs.push(wantedUrl);
    });
  }).get();

  return hrefs;
}
```

I decided that I'd like to get the links in the `<nav>` element which are usually wrapped inside `<ul>` and elements of `<li>`. So we just take those.

Then you need a workflow to work with those links. This is where the `for` loop is. I decided that I wanted the title of each page.

```js
async function mainFlow() {
  const urls = await grabLinksFromUrl('https://netzpolitik.org/');
  for (const url of urls) {
    const source = await getSourceFromUrl(url);

    const $ = cheerio.load(source);
    // Netpolitik has two <title> in their <head>
    const title = $('head > title').first().text();
    console.log(`${title} (${url}) has source of ${source.length} size`);

    // TODO: More work in here
  }
}
```

And finally, you need to call that workflow function:

```js
return mainFlow();
```

The result you see on your screen should look like this:

```
Dossiers & Recherchen (https://netzpolitik.org/dossiers-recherchen/) has source of 413853 size
Der Netzpolitik-Podcast (https://netzpolitik.org/podcast/) has source of 333354 size
14 Tage (https://netzpolitik.org/14-tage/) has source of 402312 size
Official Netzpolitik Shop (https://netzpolitik.merchcowboy.com/) has source of 47825 size
Über uns (https://netzpolitik.org/ueber-uns/#transparenz) has source of 308068 size
Über uns (https://netzpolitik.org/ueber-uns) has source of 308068 size
netzpolitik.org-Newsletter (https://netzpolitik.org/newsletter) has source of 291133 size
netzwerk (https://netzpolitik.org/netzwerk/?via=nav) has source of 299694 size
Spenden für netzpolitik.org (https://netzpolitik.org/spenden/?via=nav) has source of 296190 size
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I kind of lost. I'll need to insert the loop you share within the code I already have or which other changes should be done? I need to delete the request () part completely? Maybe you could show a more complete example please if you have the chance, since I'm very new to JavaScript and nodejs. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer. Perhaps now it's better to understand what I meant.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. Now I get your idea now. This seems to work for me. I was wondering if always is needed to create a package.json? If I only have your script within a js file would work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Mh... It's possible to use it without the package.json but it's rather inconvenient. You can just develop your app and if you want to keep it private, just execute `npm pack` and the package will be packed to something.tgz. You can install this with `npm install something.tgz` and have it deployed nicely.